# How to set a popup window on markers with Google Maps API?

Tags: visualforce, popup, google-map

I have this code where I display and set all my markers. Right now when clicking on a marker, a new tab is opened with the information which is another visualforce page. How can I have this new window open as a popup window instead? Ideally grey out the main window while the popup is opened.

```
<apex:page controller="AHS_gmaps_ctrl" action="{!init}" sidebar="false" showChat="false" showheader="false">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

 var arraddress= new Array();
 var arrlastinspect= new Array();
 var arrids= new Array();
 var content=new Array();
 var arrnames= new Array();
 var i=0;

 var map;
 var geocoder;
function initialize() 
{

 var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
 map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, 
 {
 zoom: 14,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
 }
 );
 google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', addMarkers);
 }

 function addMarkers() 
 {
 for (var i = 0; i < arraddress.length; i++) 
 {
 content[i] = '<b>'+arrnames[i]+'</b>'+'<br>'+arraddress[i]+'<br>'+'Last Inspection Date: '+arrlastinspect[i];
 geocodeAddress(arraddress[i],arrids[i],content[i]);
 }
 }

 function geocodeAddress(addds,id,content)
 {
 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

 geocoder.geocode( {'address': addds}, function(results, status) 
 {
 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
 {
 map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: results[0].geometry.location});
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: content});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() { infowindow.open(map,this);});

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {infowindow.close();});
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {window.open('{!retUrl}' + 'inspectionhistory?Id=' + id)});
 }
 else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) 
 { 
  //setTimeout(function() {geocodeAddress(addds, id, content);}, 200);
 }
 else 
 {
 alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
 }
 });
 }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
 <body style="font-family: Arial; border: 0 none;">
 <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 750px; height: 500px"></div>

 <apex:repeat value="{!Inspections}" var="inspection">
 <script>
 arrnames[i]='{!inspection.Account__r.Name}';
 arraddress[i]='{!inspection.Full_Address__c}';
 arrlastinspect[i]=' {!inspection.Account__r.Last_Inspection_Date_Short__c}';

 arrids[i]='{!inspection.Account__r.id}';
  i++;
 </script>
 </apex:repeat>
 </body>
 </html>
</apex:page>
```